# Regarding activiti 6.0.0

Tags: java

In activiti 5.22.0 end event of the task is fire before the next task is started, but in activity 6.0.0 it will not fire end event before starting the next task.

Is any one know how to hot end event before starting next task.

```
        <extensionElements>

            <activiti:executionListener

                expression=“${callbacks.onEntryOrderVerification(execution)}"

                event="start" />

            <activiti:executionListener

                expression="${callbacks.onExitOrderVerification(execution)}"

                event="end" />

        </extensionElements>

    </receiveTask>
```

```
        <extensionElements>

            <activiti:executionListener

                expression="${callbacks.onEntryDeliveringOrder(execution)}"

                event="start" />

            <activiti:executionListener

                expression="${callbacks.onExitDeliveringOrder(execution)}"

                event="end" />

        </extensionElements>

    </receiveTask>
```